# When did these nested if statements become legal?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

```
if (blah.Text != string.Empty)
    if (rowViewFilter == string.Empty)
        rowViewFilter = string.Format("(name = '{0}')", blah.Text);
    else
        rowViewFilter += string.Format(" and (name = '{0}')", blah.Text);
```

I thought I would need braces after the first line. But it seems to work just fine. For the record, I'm using VS2012, .NET 4.5, C#.

Comment: Probably in C# 1.0 as far as the history of C# is concerned. If you count older languages then you can add a few more decades.

Comment: One issue with omitting the braces in the code in the OP is the "dangling else" can be confusing dependant on indentation.

Comment: That's been legal as far back as B, if I'm reading [this manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/kbman.html) right.  Not that it's gotten any easier to read when you do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

These have always been legal in C#.  In C#, the braces are optional, and only required if a the block is more than a single statement.

The Section 5.3.3.5 of the C# spec states that an "If Statement" is `if (expr) then-stmt`, so any statement can follow an `if`.

The `if` is followed by a statement.  8.2 of the C# language spec allows braces to enclose a *statement-list*, which then forms a "block".  A block, from the spec:

> permits multiple statements to be written in contexts where a single statement is allowed.

In your case, the first `if`  is followed by a statement comprised of your second `if` statement.

Comment: The terminology for this is a "simple if" statement.

Comment: @syb0rg Who's terminology?  There isn't anything in the C# spec using that terminology that I can find...

Comment: @ReedCopsey What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: @BhushanFirake I didn't downvote you, but I suspect it's because you didn't really explain why - just showed another way to write the code that's equivalent.

Comment: @ReedCopsey That's the proper name for them in Java, I read it in a book somewhere.  That's probably why you can't find the C# spec :P

Comment: @ReedCopsey I didn't mean that you downvoted me. Sorry, if you felt so. I just asked it out of curiousity, due to 2 downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Technically your nested if/else statement:

```
if (rowViewFilter == string.Empty)
    rowViewFilter = string.Format("(name = '{0}')", blah.Text);
else
    rowViewFilter += string.Format(" and (name = '{0}')", blah.Text);
```

is all one "block" or "line" of code as far as the original if-statement is concerned.

At no point is any if-statement handling more than a single block.

Comment: The technical term for a "block" or "line" in this context is a statement, to be precise.

Comment: @Servy Yes - "block" is actually the term when a statement list is surrounded by braces, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that statement. In the absence of braces the first If includes only the following block or line. Since the next line starts another If block, all of it is included. It has always been legal in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Those have been legal all the time.

This creates confusion called the [Dangling Else Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), as the `else` belongs to the nearest `if`, and one might believe it belongs to the first one.

Answer (score -1):

This has **always** been legal in C#. This is because you can omit the braces when the block spans multiple statements. It is same as

```
if (blah.Text != string.Empty)
{
    if (rowViewFilter == string.Empty)
    {
        rowViewFilter = string.Format("(name = '{0}')", blah.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        rowViewFilter += string.Format(" and (name = '{0}')", blah.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoters: Care to comment , what has gone wrong in this?

Comment: Nothing, now that you have edited the post. It was syntactically completely wrong before.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen I haven't changed anything except the code formatting..

Comment: But please note that the question here is `When did these nested if statements become legal?`. You have not touched on that subject at all.